# Is there a way to use a SQL computed column in a table constraint without making it a persisted column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to allow for only one input per company each month, is this possible without adding an extra column to the table itself?

the code I wrote raises the error: RROR: syntax error at or near "("
the data type of size_date is date, and company_id is integer

```
ALTER TABLE companies
  ADD CONSTRAINT company_one_per_month UNIQUE(company_id, extract(month from size_date)as size_month);
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a valid Postgres error message. Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete and exact error message and the data types of all columns involved.

Comment: Note that your attempt, if successful, would prevent duplicates across years as well. Once a row for company with e.g. 2022-10-04 is created, you wouldn't be able to create another one with e.g. 2023-10-15

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a unique constraint on an expression, but a unique index. Moreover, your choice of extracting the month is questionable, since the month does not include the year.

A possible index could be as follows:

1. if the type of `size_date` is `date` or `timestamp without time zone`:

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON companies
      (company_id, date_trunc('month', size_date::timestamp));
   ```
2. if the type of `size_date` is `timestamp with time zone`:

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON companies
      (company_id, date_trunc('month', size_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'));
   ```

We have to consider the different cases, because index expressions have to be immutable, so we have to choose an expression that does *not* depend on the current setting of `timezone`.

Comment: the data type of size_date is date, your first index seems like an ideal way to add the constraint I'm looking to add. Thank you for your help :)